# How to retrieve a value in a json object in sqlite when the key is an empty string?

Tags: json, sqlite, sqlite-json1

I am processing an sqlite table which contains json objects. These json objects have keys that are empty strings. How can I retrieve the value? For example:

```
select json_extract('{"foo": "bar", "":"empty"}', '$.foo') as data;
-result: "bar"
```

How can I retrieve "empty"?

Comment: Who had the bright idea to generate json like that? You might have to use `json_each()` in a subquery...

Comment: Did you try something like '$[""]' ?

Comment: I know @Shawn, it's terrible. That's how the data was dumped and now unfortunately I am stuck with it. Can you please elaborate how I could use `json_each()` to get the value where key is an empty string `""`?

Comment: I have tried `$[""]`, but it is not a valid sqlite json path and it returns an error @jnr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example:

```
sqlite> SELECT value FROM json_each('{"foo":"bar","":"empty"}') WHERE key = '';
value     
----------
empty
```

As part of a larger query from a table:

```
SELECT (SELECT j.value FROM json_each(t.your_json_column) AS j WHERE j.key = '') AS data
FROM your_table AS t;
```